# Smart filter saved in "my analysis"

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, spagobi

I'm using SpagoBI and I would like to acces to smart filter I saved but i can't find it in the folder their show me "my analysis". 
I know this folder is present in user account, so i tried to save the smart filter into biuser (in fact i tried to save it everywhere) and I can found it in any folder.

I tried to change the folder of my smart filter on the detail of the document but i can't see it from biuser...

Do you have I idea about what to do to save my chart ?

Regards,
Wazzouille

Comment: you can also check in biadmin it usaully deploy there

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, I have finish this work for a long time now ^^ But thanks anyway, that could help people